# XamNumericEditor format and mask

Tags: mask

I'm using a XamNumericEditor control and I would like to display the value 0.000 as default. When I click on the spin button it should increment by 0.005 points. It should also support negative numbers. The maximum limit should be 100.000. Kindly let me know what would be the format and mask for this scenario.

Also, kindly point me to a link where I can learn about using the right mask and format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found out this.

I don't require the format property. Mask is -nn.nnn and Value is set to 0.000 by default and spinincrement is set to .005

Thanks